# Getting Coverage for Windows Explorer Context Menu Application!

Tags: c, windows, code-coverage, contextmenu, atl

I have an application which runs using the context menu of windows explorer. I create an ATL based DLL and register it to Windows Registry under HKCR\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers. I am able to run my application. I want coverage for my code present in the DLL which is being registered in the registry.

I am currently using IBM Rational Pure Coverage for my other applications. How to use it for getting coverage here? In case of other normal applications, we can instrument the DLL using the Pure Coverage UI and run all the testcases. But, in this case I am not clear how to go about the same? Also, if it is not possible using rational pure coverage, what are the other tools available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some amount of research, I have figured out the solution for this. In Pure Coverage there is a mechanism for instrumenting DLLs only. We can instrument a DLL in permanent instrumentation mode, so that whenever any exe invokes it, the coverage will be recorded.

With this mechanism, coverage can obtained for Windows Explorer Context Menu Application.